# Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix - Unknown reason

Tags: android

I was following a tutorial and after it was done i keep getting this error. I dont know why. any help would be helpful.

```
<supports-screens
   android:anyDensity= "true"
   android:largeScreens= "true"
   android:normalScreens= "true"
   android:resizeable= "true"
   android:smallScreens= "true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<activity
   android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
  <intent-filter></intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I am geting the error on all these lines

```
<supports-screens
   android:anyDensity= "true"
   android:largeScreens= "true"
   android:normalScreens= "true"
   android:resizeable= "true"
   android:smallScreens= "true" />
```

And to me it doesn't make sense why it is appearing, I have specified that it is android but it doesn't seem to relise it

Comment: This may sound silly, or you may have tried it but... clean project?

Comment: I do that but then at the end of supportscreen snipit i get "The prefix "android" for attribute "android:anyDensity" associated with an element type "supports-screens" is not bound."

Comment: is it because you haven't declared the android namespace at the top of the xml file?

Comment: @ damon Smith, Derp :P i did to thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation score to comment, so I'll try to answer your question here:

```
android:resizeable
```

This attribute is deprecated. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) for more info regarding `<supports-screens>`.

Also, I don't see in your post your settings for:

```
android:minSdkVersion
android:targetSdkVersion
```

You need to declare these values in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: This was a simple mistake on my behalf where i forgot to specify some info before the application, I solved this by placing the following code at the beginning of the application. with retrospective closing of manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mayukh.helloworld"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```